# groupByKey not properly working in spark

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

So, I have an RDD, which has key-value pair like following.

```
(Key1, Val1)
(Key1, Val2)
(Key1, Val3)
(Key2, Val4)
(Key2, Val5)
```

After groupByKey, I expect to get something like this

```
Key1, (Val1, Val2, Val3)
Key2, (Val4, Val5)
```

However, I see that same keys are being repeated even after doing groupByKey(). The total number of key value pairs are certainly reduced, but still there are many duplicate keys. What could be the problem?

The type of the key is basically a Java class with fields of integer types. Could it be that spark is also considering things other than the fields of the objects for identifying those objects?

Comment: I do not know exact reason for this issue. But i would suggest you to use reducebykey. It is performance wise better than groupbykey. Also in large cases groupbykey can cause you serious problems.

Comment: @shivams: But isn't reduceBykey used for a different purpose? Like for example summing up values for a key? While groupForKey is for collecting the values in a list for a given key? Or no?

Comment: shivams assumes you're going to do aggregation on the lists. That's what happens most of the time. But if you need the actual lists, then `groupByKey` is your ticket.

Comment: reduceByKey should be preferred over groupByKey where possible, however there are perfectly good reasons for using both as you say. Although that is beside the point of the question!

In your Java class, have you correctly overridden .equals and hashcode()?

Can you post some of your code if not?

Comment: @dpeacock: I was just stalling so I could beat you for the answer :).

Comment: @DanielDarabos Okey i read that reducebykey is better than groupbykey. But i think that every case of groupbykey cannot be replaced. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupByKey` and a lot of other methods in Spark rely on object hashes. If two instances of your class do not return the same `hashCode` then Spark will not consider them equal even if all their fields are equal.

Make sure you override `equals` and `hashCode`!